# Why is my NodeJS server deployed to Elastic Beanstalk receiving HTTPS traffic on port 80?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, https, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've written a very simply NodeJS server

```
var http = require("http");

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
   response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
   response.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(80);
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8081/');
```

I then deployed it to Elastic Beanstalk with the "Classic Load Balancer" option selected.

Oddly, the server responds to traffic sent with `https`.

I expected that it would not know how to handle this traffic since the server is only listening on port 80, which is for `http` (no `s`).

Does anyone have an explanation or at least idea of why my NodeJS is handling non-HTTPS requests?

Comment: Actually, the default node.js + elastic beanstalk include nginx/ apache server which behaves as a load balancer, access logger, security layer with https as described here
https://www.nginx.com/blog/5-performance-tips-for-node-js-applications/ so you can also set the https certificate in the web server while your app always listen on http but your traffic is secure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `https` request made, it is terminated at the Load Balancer. The Load Balancer then will make an `http` request to the listener aka the NodeJS apps. This is the default configuration of Load Balancer in ElasticBeanstalk.

So your NodeJS apps is handling an `http` request from the Load Balancer instead of the `https` directly from the client.

Comment: Ah ok thanks! Do you know then how I could force load balancer to only accept HTTPS ?

Comment: AFAIK, there is no out-of-the-box to force the HTTPS only on Load Balancer. In NodeJS, you may want to check for `x-forwarded-proto` header, where if the header is not `https`, then response with redirect to https. In my case, I usually attach Cloudfront in front of ELB and force HTTPS at the Cloudfront

Comment: But if I check in NodeJS I'll only be seeing the LB request and not the original user's request, right? So that won't help me too much

Comment: The `x-forwarded-proto` header is client's protocol in request. ELB forwarded the header if client is using `https`